# Azure pipeline stage name contains dash

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline yml which run stage for each product given by parameters.

I have now a new product which contains dash in its name and the pipeline fails to run due to invalid character in the stage name - only allowed letter, numbers and underscore

I'd like to replace dashes to underscore in the product name.

My current yml:

```
parameters:
  - name: product
    type: object
  - name: component
    type: string
  - name: configuration
    type: string  

stages:
  - ${{ each product in parameters.product }}:
    - stage: ${{ product }}_build
```

I have tried:

```
stages:
  - ${{ each product in parameters.product }}:
    - stage: $[replace(${{ product }}, '-', '_')]_build
```

Which fails on a product without dash

Is there any way I can replace product name only if it contains dash, something like if-else?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
stages:
  - ${{ each product in parameters.product }}:
    - stage: ${{replace(product, '-', '_')}}_build
```